# Spring Security ignoring multiple HTTP configurations

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have been working on a web app with Spring Security that has some complex requirements (support for both database and LDAP authentication, login page and API) for which I have mostly figured out except one thing which I just can't get: handling multiple http.  I'm doing everything in JAVA, no web.xml.  With Spring debugging on, it recognizes all three but it appears to only be comparing the request against the first http and then moving on.  Here is my code:

**AppConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan( { "com.mydomain.security" } )
@Import( { SecurityConfig.class } )
public class AppConfig{
    ...
}
```

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig{

    @Autowired
    Config cfg;

    @Autowired
    LdapContextSource ldapContextSource;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier( "authenticationProviderDB" )
    AuthenticationProvider authenticationProviderDB;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier( "authenticationProviderLDAP" )
    AuthenticationProvider authenticationProviderLDAP;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier( "persistentRememberMeServices" )
    static RememberMeServices persistentRememberMeServices;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier( "tokenRepository" )
    CustomTokenRepository tokenRepository;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal( AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth )throws Exception{
        auth.authenticationProvider( authenticationProviderLDAP );
        auth.authenticationProvider( authenticationProviderDB );
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order( 1 )                                                        
    public static class RestWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers( "/api/**" ).hasRole("ROLE_USER").and().httpBasic()
            .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage( "/security/api" )
        }
    }

    @Configuration                                                   
    public static class FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
        @Override
        protected void configure( HttpSecurity http )throws Exception{
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers( "/**" ).hasRole("ROLE_USER")
            .and().formLogin().loginPage( "/security/login" ).failureUrl( "/security/login?error" ).usernameParameter( "username" ).passwordParameter( "password" )
            .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_valuehere")
            .and().rememberMe().rememberMeServices( persistentRememberMeServices ).key( "key" )
            .and().addFilterBefore( (Filter)new CustomErrorHandlerFilter(), RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .csrf().disable();
        }
    }
}
```

**Logs**

```
8075 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy  - /index.jsp at position 10 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
8076 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  - Checking match of request : '/index.jsp'; against '/security/**'
8076 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor  - Public object - authentication not attempted
8077 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy  - /index.jsp reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
```

Any help to what I may be missing is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can try .hasRole("USER") in case earlier edits don't work

Comment: Thanks but that didn't solve it.

Comment: If I add @Order(1) to FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and change it to @Order(2) on RestWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter, then everything starts working except the API.  It appears that Spring is only picking up the first class extending WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and ignoring the rest.  Is there an annotation I need to add somewhere to force it to use all?

Comment: Could you please provide trace level logs to see what's happening? if possible try xml approch to see if that works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers( "/api/**" ).hasRole("ROLE_USER").and().httpBasic()
        .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage( "/security/api" )
```

to

```
http.antMatcher("/api/**").authorizeRequests().antMatchers( "/api/**" ).hasRole("ROLE_USER").and().httpBasic()
        .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage( "/security/api" )
```

That will override the `/**` chain you've set up.